# How to handle special character (!) in folder name using batch program

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am using the below script to filter the XML files from folder based on search ID and return the XML file name into export.txt.

It works fine if the folder name doesnot contain the special character (!). In my case folders will have (!). Can anyone help, how to handle this sinario. How to tackle with special characters in folder name.

Could you Please provide your sample working code?

{

```
@echo off
echo. >export.txt
set searchid="<sh:InstanceIdentifier>SBDH_4539594000005_tt7x7c71fof8d9adenhr<"
for /f %%a in ('findstr /i /m %searchid% C:\ABC!DEF\*.xml') do (
  echo %%a >>export.txt
)
```

}

Comment: The `!` is not a special character unless you have delayed expansion enabled, which you don't have above.  Just pointing this out for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this page as a reference: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

```
! = ^^!
```

Comment: The linked page is not a great reference - there are some inaccuracies

Answer (score 1):

If delayed expansion is enabled and any given line of code contains a `!` character anywhere within it, then the following unusual escape sequences are required if you want a string literal:

```
unquoted ! = ^^!
quoted !   = ^!
unquoted ^ = ^^^^
quoted ^   = ^^
```

If delayed expansion is enabled but line does not contain `!`, then `^` is escaped normally:

```
unquoted ^ = ^^
quoted ^   = ^
```

If delayed expansion is disabled, then `!` does not require escape, and `^` is escaped normally:

```
unquoted ! = !
quoted !   = !
unquoted ^ = ^^
quoted ^   = ^
```

Comment: Many Thanks, I have added delayed expansion and used ^^ as prefix to ! and it worked fine....{findstr /i /m %searchid% C:\ABC^^!DEF\*.xml}....Many Thanks... :)